# Trying to send data to text file

Tags: java, jbutton, jtextfield

Hi there I made a program that consist of jtextfield and couple jbuttons. I want to press a jbutton so that the jtextfields will be save to the computer. Any help will be useful.

Comment: Why don't you look up a tutorial on saving data to a file? They are abundant

Comment: What have you already tried so far?

Comment: So what is your problem? Do you know how to do file I/O? Do you know how to execute code when a button is clicked? Do you know how to get text from a text field? Be specific when you ask a question. We can't guess what is causing you problems. Start with the `Java Tutorials`. There are tutorial on I/O and using Swing that should answer all your questions.

Comment: I know how to make a button work. I have a text field but do not know how to send it to a text file.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you..

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    if (jTxt_text.getText().isEmpty()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Field is empty. Fill the filed and try again.");
    } else {
        //get the text from the jTextField and save it into a varibale. 
        String inputText = jTxt_text.getText();
        //Where to save the file.
        String savePath = "C:/test/sample.txt";

        //Creating a file object, file is an abstract representation of file and directory pathnames.
        File tempFile = new File(savePath);

        //Check wther the file is available or not.
        if (!tempFile.exists()) {
            try {
                //Creates the file if it's not exsising.
                tempFile.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        try {
            //writing process..
            FileWriter tempWriter = new FileWriter(tempFile.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter tempBufferWriter = new BufferedWriter(tempWriter);
            tempBufferWriter.write(inputText);
            tempBufferWriter.close();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Text file with the written text is successfully saved.");
            jTxt_text.setText(null);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Still there's a small problem with this code `tempBufferWriter.write(inputText)` returns void so.. i don't know how to check wther the process completed successfully from the code itself..

Comment: I have many text fields to write at the same time 15 to be exact they do not all have to be field. So using this code should work for writing all of them?

Comment: this is a basic code where you can get the value of a `jTextField` and write it to a text file... there could be `jTextAreas`, `JComboBoxes`, `jRadioButtons` so what you have to do is simply get all the values from a those components and save then into variables and build a separate string. and pass it as the parameter fo the write method.